# Not able to trigger DAG from Airflow API but its working from Curl command

Tags: rest, airflow, airflow-scheduler

- I am trying to trigger DAG from Airflow API through python script.
- DAG is triggering from curl command but its not working from API.

```
import requests

url ='http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/document_validation/dag_runs'
myobj = {''}

x =requests.post(url, data=myobj, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

print(x.text)
```

Error I am getting

```
  File "run_dag_api.py", line 6, in <module>  
  `x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)`  
  File "/…/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post  
  `return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)`  
  File "/…/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request  
  `return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)`  
  File "/…/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request  
  `resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)`  
  File "/…/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send  
  `r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)`  
  File "/…/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send  
  `raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)`  
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```